# ubuntu 12.04 acer idea issues

Tags: 12.04, acer

So I was trying to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS onto my acer iDea 510. 
I succeeded to install it, though everytime I try to install the wireless and graphics card drivers it crashes and send this message that it "can't enumerate usb device port 3" over and over again. I tried to reinstall it several times with no success. 
Do you have any idea?

Thank you very much for you're help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install legacy firmware/drivers for the older wireless and graphics cards in the iDea 510.  This should fix the USB port enumeration errors.

For the graphics card, if you have drivers currently installed, remove them:

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-vesa
```

Next, edit sources.list to add a non free repository:

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Add the following line to the end of the file:

`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free`

Save and close.

Now update and add the legacy nVidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install nvidia-kernel-legacy-173xx-dkms nvidia-glx-legacy-173xx build-essential nvidia-settings nvidia-xconfig
```

After it's downloaded, execute the Xconfig file:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo reboot
```

When you reboot, it should load back up normally.

For the wireless card, download the firmware-b43-installer and it should automatically extract and install everything for you ([Source](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/)):

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

You will be asked to automatically fetch and install the firmware into the correct location.